# How to add to a custom graph activities button?

Tags: acumatica

I created my own DAC and Graph following the framework guidelines, but I want to show Activities button on the right corner on the screen, how can I show this button? Is there an attribute? or an special field on the dac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DAC needs a NoteID field, and then you can set ActivityIndicator = True on the primary view.

DAC

```
#region NoteID
[PXNote()]
public override Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
public new abstract class noteID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<noteID> { }
#endregion
```

Customization Project - ActivityIndicator

[image: Activity Indicator]

Comment: Excelent! I had the PXNote attribute but I could find out how to add the activities tab. It Worked! Thanks